Stripe payment fails email notification
Does stripe sends mail automatically to the customer for failed or unsuccessful payments without subscription:
below is the code that I am using for one time payment-
const paymentIntent = await stripeKey.paymentIntents.create({
          amount: amount,
          currency: 'usd',
          customer: customerId,
          payment_method: defaultPaymentMethod, // Use the default payment method
          confirm: true,
          receipt_email: customer.email,
          return_url: url
        });

does stripe send mail to the receipt_email when payment failed or not succeed? If not then what steps needs to be done? and is there any need to provide return_url?

These feel more like questions for Stripe product support than coding questions for StackOverflow?
In any case AFAIK such emails are not sent no, you write code to catch the error and present it to the customer immediately since it's an on-session payment.

After talking with the support, I found out that the failed email notification only applies for subscriptions and not for one-time payments.
